# Clickonce - External url intranet

Tags: c#, clickonce, intranet

I am using a clickonce application (c#) in a intranet network.
And I notice that the application try to check external url like clientservices.googleapis.com, ctldl.windowsupdate.com.
The problem that slows down the start of the application installation (25 seconds). I saw that the update windows options have an impact (information found with internet and I tried all the options).
Exemple:

- Install updates automatically ==> slow down 25s
- Never check for updates ==> no slow down
- Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them ==> no slow down

But do you know if there is a click once option to stop the external url calls without I had to modified the update windows options of all the IT infrastructure ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to the community! Please edit your post to outline what you have tried and the research you have already done, so people that try to help have more to work with.

Comment: Hi Nik, thanks for yours advices. I tried to add some additional informations.